# SQL - Select from column A based on values in column B

Tags: sql, t-sql

Lets say I have a table with 2 columns (**a**, **b**) with following values:

```
 a     b
---   ---
 1     5
 1    NULL 
 2    NULL
 2    NULL
 3    NULL
```

My desired output:

```
 a
---
 2
 3
```

I want to select only those distinct values from column **a** for which every single occurrence of this value has NULL in column **b**. Therefore from my desired output, "1" won't come in because there is a "5" in column **b** even though there is **a** NULL for the 2nd occurrence of "1".

How can I do this using a TSQL query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select a
from t
group by a
having count(b) = 0;
```

When you use `count()` with a column name, it counts the number of non-NULL values.  Hence, if all values are `NULL`, then the value will be zero.

Comment: Maybe explain why this works (nulls are not counted)

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly simple to do:

```
SELECT A
FROM table1
GROUP BY A
HAVING COUNT(B) = 0
```

Grouping by A results in all the rows where the value of A is identical to be transferred into a single row in the output. Adding the `HAVING` clause enables to filter those grouped rows with an aggregate function. `COUNT` doesn't count `NULL` values, so when it's 0, there are no other values in B.

Answer (score 2):

Two more ways to do this:

```
SELECT a
FROM t

EXCEPT

SELECT a
FROM t
WHERE b IS NOT NULL ;
```

This would use an index on `(a, b)`:

```
SELECT a
FROM t
GROUP BY a
WHERE MIN(b) IS NOT NULL ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(a INT, b INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,5),(1,NULL),(2,NULL),(2,NULL),(3,NULL);
--Your test data
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

--And this is what you want - hopefully...
SELECT DISTINCT tbl.a
FROM @tbl AS tbl
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @tbl AS x WHERE x.a=tbl.a AND b IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: @Hogan it could be faster. Did you test?

Comment: @ypercube, I did not test it, but I'd assume, that with indexes the NOT EXISTS approach is lightning fast... But I must admit the COUNT approach is very sexy :-)

Answer (score 0):

To turn your question on it's head, you want the values from column `a` where there are no non-null values for that value in column `b`.

```
select distinct a
from table1 as t1
where 0 = (select count(*) 
           from table1 as t2
           where t1.a = t2.a
           and b is not null)
```

Sample fiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d1b8/1

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a
FROM t
WHERE b IS NULL
AND a NOT IN (SELECT a FROM t WHERE b IS NOT NULL);
```